# Jquery Countdown - how to make this code work? [Edited]

Tags: jquery

I was looking for an easy jquery countdown code, and found a certain website that was using the following code:

```
  var endTime = new Date("10/08/2014 01:00 PM");

  $('#time').countdown({
      serverSync: function(){return new Date("10/08/2014 08:33 AM");},
      until: endTime,
      layout: '{hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, {sn} {sl}',
      onExpiry: reloadPage,
      expiryText: 'It"s finally here!'
  });
```

HTML:

```
Time left: <span id="time" class="hasCountdown"></span>
```

But it doesn't work on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3cab4ko/1/), so I guess some things are missing, as I didn't take the code from a tutorial but rather straight from that website.

How to make this work? (or any similar form if this can be enhanced).

In that website, the real HTML was showing this code that kept switching:

`<span id="time" class="hasCountdown">4 Hours, 0 Minutes, 57 Seconds</span>`

Personally I'm not sure I'd like to use the phrases `hours` and `minutes`, but I'm not sure how to take them off or write alternate text as these words aren't showing in the code...

**EDIT:**

Ok, I didn't notice the external source, just added it to the fiddle, still doesn't work though.

Comment: I guess you should include the `countdown` plugin as well for this to work.

Comment: The fiddle wont work if you don't include the external resource you are using. Where did you get the countdown plugin from?

Comment: @ZiNNED sorry, didn't notice it, I've added it now, but still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are using a jQuery plugin for the countdown. Note `.countdown(...)`. I'd look for that plugin and include it in the page.

Possibly: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: Yes that's the script, but I Can't get it to work still.

Comment: Look at the documentation on jQuery Countdown. There are many examples of how it works. I wouldn't reference the source you pulled it from as they using a vary strange implementation of `serverSync`.